# Load ViewController into ContainerView prior to showing so no transition is visible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Using Swift 4+, iOS 11.4+, Xcode 10+

I'm using a ContainerView with a Navigation controller to load multiple ViewControllers.

In addition, the ViewController that holds the ContainerView is also pushed onto a different NavigationController stack.

See this graphic:

[image]

The "Menu" is the root controller in the stack.
I am pushing another ViewController (TopViewController) onto the same stack - so far so good.

My issue is that I want to "pre-load" the TopViewController > ContainerView with a different ViewController (Item1) ***before*** the TopViewController becomes visible.

There are other ViewControllers in addition Item1 that I will need to "pre-load" in this manner.

I have tried using "viewDidLoad" in TopViewController to push Item1,

```
toVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Item1") as! Item1
TopNav.pushViewController(toVC, animated: true)
```

and it works - but only after TopViewController becomes visible.
This means that you can see Item1 "pop" into view rather than already being visible.

I have also tried this code from within the Menu VC, but it does not push anything onto the ContainerView.

```
let toVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TopViewController") as! TopViewController
        
// Tried this to 'pre-load' the next VC - shows no VC, and disables 'back' navigation
let toNav = toVC.navigationController
let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Item1") as! Item1
// Neither of the lines below loads the Item1 VC....
//toNav?.viewControllers = [nextVC]
toNav.pushViewController(toVC, animated: true)
```

How can I push Item1 onto the Navigation stack for the ContainerView before the VC with the ContainerView becomes visible?

FYI: You can download my sample project here: https://gitlab.com/whoit/newviews

Comment: I'm using the Storyboard "ContainerView" object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>    TopNav.pushViewController(toVC, animated: true)
> ```
>
> and it works - but only after TopViewController becomes visible.

Because you asked for animation. Change `animated: true` to `animated: false` If that’s what you want.

---

The preceding is right, but there were a lot of other issues with your project.

Most important, *your container view has no constraints*. This causes it to end up the wrong size. Give it constraints in the storyboard.

Second, do what I said above: push `toVC` with `false` animation.

Third, you need to preload your top view controller's view, like this:

```
@IBAction func Item1_Tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let toVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
        withIdentifier: "TopViewController") as! TopViewController
    toVC.loadViewIfNeeded() // add this line
    // then delete all the other useless stuff
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Changing the value doesn't make a difference. Using ".viewControllers = [nextVC]" is basically the same as using 'false'. Either way, the new VC becomes visible first, then Item1 pops into view.

Comment: Ok so maybe you need to ask the top view controller to load its view earlier?

Comment: I just added a link to my sample project in the OP if you are interested...

Comment: Yep - it was the "loadViewIfNeeded" method that solved it - thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant in my comment when I said "ask the top view controller to load its view earlier".

Comment: Didn't know about that method - but I won't forget it now - thanks! (Tom Terrific? Haven't seen him in many years...:)

Comment: You are the first person to know who he is!

Comment: It used to be my favorite cartoon!!

Comment: Mine too but that was in 1959!

Comment: What are the chances I can get you to look at another issue I'm having? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54171258/music-info-showing-in-command-center-but-not-lock-screen

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're wanting is a way to manage child view controllers, correct? (childVC1 = item1, childVC2 = item2, etc.)

If that is the case, [this may help](https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers).

Another route would embedding your `TopViewController` into a `TabBarController`, and hiding the tab bar. Then when an item is selected, you load the `TopViewController` with the tab index associated with the item.

**Edit:**

What you can do is have a navigation controller in place of your `TopViewContorller` that sets the `rootViewController` based on the selected item. In terms of your code, theres a little maintenance work needed to get this smooth:

1. Get rid of your base `UINavigationController` and have your `MenuViewController` as your initial `ViewController`.
2. Add segues on each item that segue to the same `UINavigationController`.
3. In `MenuViewController` override `prepare(for:, sender:)` and initialize the `UIViewController` associated with the selected item. You can do this by naming the segues and switching on the names, or matching the sender to the button.

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       switch segue.identifier {

       case "item1Segue":
           guard let item1VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Item1") else { return assertionFailure() }
           item1VC.title = "Item1"
           (segue.destination as UINavigationController)?.setViewControllers([item1VC], animated: false)

       case "item2Segue":
           guard let item2VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Item2") else { return assertionFailure() }
           item2VC.title = "Item2" UINavigationController)?.setViewControllers([item2VC], animated: false)
           // And so on
       }
   }
   ```

   To get the same UI as you had with the `TopViewController`, add a back & also bar buttons to the Item viewControllers, title follows by setting the title as seen in the code.

Comment: I just added a link to my sample project in the OP if you are interested...

Comment: Checking it out now

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be done without adding more controls - I'd prefer it that way...

Comment: Updating answer based on your code base, give me a sec

Comment: I updated my answer, there's other things you might want to look at with your code that I'd be happy to help with if you're interested. My twitter and git are linked in my profile

Comment: Thanks for the help, but see above for the solution - a single line of code that I didn't know about.